# how to use setSupportActionBar in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I need to use the setSupportActionBar in fragment which I am unable to also I am unable to use setContentView please to help with it also Thankyou in advance
the related code is given

```
public class StudentrFragment extends Fragment {
        Toolbar toolbar;
        TabLayout tabLayout;
        ViewPager viewPager;
        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;


        public StudentrFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.tabbar_layout);
            toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar); 
            tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
            viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new CivilFragment(),"Civil Dept");
            viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new ComputerFragment(),"CSE Dept");
            viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new EeeFragment(),"EEE Dept");
            viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new EceFragment(),"ECE Dept");
            viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Android AppBarLayout, Toolbar and TabLayout with fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32326248/how-to-use-android-appbarlayout-toolbar-and-tablayout-with-fragments)

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You can setSupportActionbar like this in fragments:

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

You need to inflate `tabbar_layout`  in `onCreateView` of `Fragment`.
Like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabbar_layout, container, false);
 //YOUR STUFF
return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Is it maybe a good idea to wrap it in: `if (getActivity() instanceof AppCompatActivity){//start using it as AppCompatActivity}`. Because you don't know how/where people use your fragment?

Comment: If you extend a support fragment, it will for sure be used in a support (AppCompat) activity, especially now with the AndroidX changes. If you really want to check (but there should be no need), `(activity as? AppCompatActivity)?.setSupportActionBar(myToolbar)` does it.

Answer (score 10):

The [suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38189630/4858777) works, but it doesn't look elegant, ideally a fragment shouldn't know anything about its parent activity. An alternative might be not to use `setSupportActionBar` at all. If you use [navigation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation) library it might be easier to add a [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/Toolbar) to the fragment layout and setup it using [NavigationUI](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui), for example:

```xml
<!-- my_fragment.xml -->
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout ... >

  <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:menu="@menu/my_fragment_menu"
    ... />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```kotlin
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
  ...

  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val navController = findNavController()
    binding.toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController)

    binding.toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
      when (it.itemId) {
        // these ids should match the item ids from my_fragment_menu.xml file
        R.id.edit -> {
          Log.i("MyFragment", "edit menu item is clicked")

          // by returning 'true' we're saying that the event 
          // is handled and it shouldn't be propagated further
          true
        }
        else -> false
      }
    }

    // if you prefer not to use xml menu file 
    // you can also add menu items programmatically
    val shareMenuItem = binding.toolbar.menu.add(R.string.share)
    shareMenuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
      Log.i("MyFragment", "share menu item is clicked")
      true
    }
  }
}
```

You can find the full GitHub example [here](https://github.com/icesmith/android-samples/tree/master/SeparateToolbars). Also take a look at another question [Is setSupportActionbar required anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33687837/4858777) and my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65255723/4858777) for more details.

Comment: Hi Valeriy, I took a look at your example and the menu seems to inflate nicely. Where would you suggest to place the code that handles menu option selection? Since in this way the `onOptionsItemSelected` method is not called anymore.

Comment: @Wafje Please take a look at the updated example, hope it helps!

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks to your example I also found the related [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/appbar#fragment-click)

Answer (score 2):

Setup support action bar for navigation menu in Kotlin :

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!.setSupportActionBar(customToolbar as Toolbar?)
```

Also to animate the hamburger icon at the toggle of DrawerLayout :

```
val actionBarDrawerToggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle = object : ActionBarDrawerToggle(activity,
                drawer_layout, customToolbar as Toolbar?, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer) { }
    
drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle)
actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()
```

Answer (score 1):

[This site has the solution which worked for me!](https://www.semicolonworld.com/question/49402/how-to-get-toolbar-from-fragment)

Pasting it:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) getView().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();

activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment's `onCreateView` function add this:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        //Set toolbar
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.*enter the fragment containing toolbar here*, container, false)
        val toolbar: Toolbar = view.findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
        (requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        return view
    }
```