# setOnClickListener not working in fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener, android-toolbar

I'm trying to set an `onclicklistener` in my fragment which has a custom toolbar included and in the toolbar I have a bell icon which I am trying to put `onclicklistener` on but isn't working

This is the toolbar `custom_toolbar.xml`

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:title="@string/app_name">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/notification_bell"
            ..>
        <ImageView
               ..>
        <ImageView
                ..>
        <TextView
                ..>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

This is the fragment.xml

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".landing.ui.fragment.HomeFragment">

    <include android:id="@+id/custom_toolbar"
             layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Then in Fragment.kt

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private fun initbell(notificationCount:Int) {

        custom_toolbar.notification_bell.setOnClickListener {
            Log.e("Fragment","bell clicked")
        }

    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        init()
        .........
    }

    private fun init() {
        initComponent()
        ..........
    }

    private fun initComponent() {
        initbell(it)
        ..........
        }

    }

}
```

When the bell is clicked I want to perform some action. Currently, I should be able to display the log.
And also Im able to access it and change its visibility so its not a problem of initiating

Comment: please add that toolbar first to your fragment using setsupportactionbar

Comment: Please read my comment properly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189198/how-to-use-setsupportactionbar-in-fragment

Comment: Sorry I have tried that (activity as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(custom_toolbar as Toolbar?) but this didnt work

Comment: and I'm also able to set text to the toolbar textview without setsupportactionbar

Comment: Can you try adding `android:clickable="false"` to your ToolBar? It might be intercepting the click not letting the RelativeLayout listen to it.

Comment: not working either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was looking into it and found that there was a small mistake that is I had to use AppBar Layout which actually solved the problem as the fragment.xml was not able to get the appbar layout so it wasn't recognizing the clicks. After this it worked like a charm

In fragment.xml

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context=".landing.ui.fragment.HomeFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
             <include 
                android:id="@+id/custom_toolbar"
                layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Alternate** :-

> Take Relative layout as the header in fragment class like this

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".landing.ui.fragment.HomeFragment">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >


    <ImageView
           ..>
    <ImageView
            ..>
    <TextView
            ..>


</RelativeLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and in `fragment` class with `onCreate()`

```
header_bar.setOnClickListener {
            Log.e("Fragment","bell clicked")
        }
```

Comment: initialized toolbar in fragment class and set it to support action bar .. please check

Comment: This one crashed app toolbar returned null

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com, PID: 8030
    kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        at com.landing.ui.fragment.HomeFragment.initbell(HomeFragment.kt:98)

Comment: check my answer now.. added new alternate for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Add an id to toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:id="@+id/tb_toolbar"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:title="@string/app_name">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/notification_bell"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Then inside fragment

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    (context as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(tb_toolbar)

    notification_bell.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Yeaey", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: remove the id given to include layout, then it'll work

Comment: Did you override `onViewCreated` function\

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to Toolbar tag in xml and then in kotlin file add bellow line in 
onViewCreated method

(context as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(your_toolbar_id)

```
    your_toolbar_id.notification_bell.setOnClickListener {
        Log.d("TAG", "Your Log message here")
    }
```

Comment: Terrible solution

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to make the RelativeLayout handle the click, you should add the `android:clickable` attribute to it:

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/notification_bell"
   android:clickable="true"
..>
```

That's because a RelativeLayout will let the touch event passed from it so the child view can handle the event.