# Android BottomNavigationView with three fragments - How to set only one to have toolbar with options

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, toolbar, android-toolbar

I have one MainActivity with FrameLayout and BottomNavigationView.
Based on BottomNavigationView selected item I load fragments inside FragmeLayout. I have three fragments, call them A,B,C.
For each of them I have defined layout xml file. For fragments A and B I don't have a toolbar but for fragment C I have defined in fragment_c.xml Toolbar(  androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar).

- I defined menu_c.xml file with one item,
- I have added this line in    Fragment_C.java
  `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in `onCreateView` method,
- I have also    added    `inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_c.xml, menu)`
  in       `onCreateOptionsMenu` method

Problem is that the menu does not apper in Fragment_C, toolbar is there but menu isn't. 
I have searched for answers and couldn't find working solution. I found that for regular toolbar with options you need to call `setSupportActionBar(actionBarToolBar)` from `onCreate` in your main activity, but I do not want toolbar to exist through all 3 fragment, I only want toolbar in my third fragment.
I do not want to hide/show toolbar with options, Is there a way to make this work with toolbar with options in only one fragment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use setSupportActionBar in fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189198/how-to-use-setsupportactionbar-in-fragment)

Answer (score 0):

First create  toolbar.xml

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

Then in fragmentC.xml include the layout toolbar

```
 <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

, thus you can call inside your fragmentC.kt inside onViewCreated() use this line

```
  toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_c)
```